# Breeze hasChanges() when editing back an entity to its original values

Tags: breeze

I have a question about the change detection of a breeze entity.

Suppose I have an entity in the `Changed` state, because just one of its string properties has changed (from `'hello'` to `'hello2'` for example).

If I change back this property to its initial value `'hello'`, I was expecting `hasChanges()` to return to `Unchanged`. But alas the state remains `Changed`.

Is this the expected behavior? If so, is there a way to make Breeze use its originalValues hash map to check for real changes instead of "dirtiness"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question.  I don't think there's a way to cause breeze to calculate the hasChanges based on a comparison, but you could probably put something together.

The originalValues hash map only contains the properties that breeze thinks have changed for the entity.  So you could write a small function to fire on the entityChanged event and do a comparison, setting the entityState to unmodified if there are no differences.

Something like:

```
em.entityChanged.subscribe(function(changeArgs) {
    var action = changeArgs.entityAction;
    var entity = changeArgs.entity;
    var ovs = entity.entityAspect.originalValues
    if (action == breeze.EntityAction.PropertyChange) {
        for (var prop in ovs) {
            if (prop in entity) {
                 // As soon as a non-matching property is discovered,
                 // then 'Modified' is the appropriate state, so exit
                 if (entity[prop] !== ovs[prop]) return;
            }
        }
        // all the properties are the same.  mark it unchanged
        entity.entityAspect.setUnchanged();
    } 
});
```

This is off the top of my head.  I don't have an environment to test it at the moment, so I'm not sure I'd trust the code as is.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank it does the job. More work is however required to handle properly empty strings and null.

Comment: @Raerd, cool.  Glad it helps.  When I get a proper environment set up I'll see if updates would make sense.  In part, it depends on how you want to treat empty strings and nulls (consider them the same or different?).